# When trying to run a model created by AutoML getting this error: Model provided has model identifier 'OCTY', should be 'TFL3'

Tags: google-coral

I am trying to use a model created and trained by AutoML. When running on Coral Edge board:
edgetpu_detect_server --model ~/edgetpu_model.tflite --labels ~/dict.txt

or

edgetpu_classify_server --model ~/edgetpu_model.tflite --labels ~/dict.txt

I am getting following runtime error:
RuntimeError: Model provided has model identifier 'OCTY', should be 'TFL3'

I am sorry,I am totally new to that thing and was trying to google for hours OCTY vs. TFL3 and can't find any info on this. 
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. It looks like it's happening if you download the model via http and not through gsutil.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an indication that the model.tflite file is corrupt in some way. The file size is a good first check. Or, if it's not a .tflite model at all and the .tflite extension has been wrongly applied to a regular tensorflow model, will get the same error.